# Prevent caching on magento cms pages

Tags: magento, caching

**Hi All**
     Is it possible to disable caching cms pages in magento ? I need to disable cache on cms pages for some reason

Comment: Can you provide more info on your issue? The Magento version and what type of cache (blocks, full page)

Comment: Hi Marius,Sorry for the late replay. magento version is 1.11.2.0.I don't want magento cache on some of the cms pages.Because some part of the code is dynamic.We cannot change the code for some reason

Answer (score 1):

In EE there are 3 types of pages that are cached. CMS pages, categories and products. Each entity is defined in `app/code/Core/Enterprise/PageCache/etc.xml` inside the tag `<cache><requests>` under the `<frontend>` tag. For cms pages there is this line

```
<cms>enterprise_pagecache/processor_default</cms>
```

This sets the processor for the cms pages.
You need to disable this cache by adding in one of your custom modules, in the config.xml this:

```
<frontend>
    ...<!-- other config settings here -->
    <cache>
        <requests>
            <cms></cms><!-- this should override the cms page cache processor to null -->
        </requests>
    </cache>
</fronend>
```

Make your module depend on `Enterprise_PageCache` module.
I haven't tested this. In case it doesn't work, you can set the cache processor to one of your models `<cms>module/cache_processor</cms>` and in your class add the method `allowCache` that should return `false`.

Comment: Hi Marius. Thank you for your replay.I tried the first method.That is not working.And I Guess if I did the second method I guess this will affect all  other store that me have in magento